# Response json in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a four table in laravel framework:

USER:
id_user,
email,
password,
profile_image,
fullname,
gender,
age,
country of residence,
city_if_residence,

EVENT
id_event,
id_user,
name_event

MEMBER_EVENTS,
id_member,
id_user,
id_event,

STORAGE
id_storage,
id_event,
name_storage,

And I have a repsonse json :

```
{
    "success": true,
    "event": [
        {
            "id_event": 1,
            "id_user": 1,
            "name_event": "new event",
            "place_event": "Chocen, wladyslawa lokietka 424",
            "time_event": "19:00",
            "description": "description",
            "first_storage_file": "1598548420.jpg",
            "longitude": "124124",
            "latitude": "12312.123123",
            "storage_file": 1,
            "storage": [
                {
                    "id_storage": 1,
                    "id_event": 1,
                    "storage_file_title": "profile.jpg",
                    "created_at": null,
                    "updated_at": null
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id_event": 2,
            "id_user": 1,
            "name_event": "new event",
            "place_event": "Chocen, wladyslawa lokietka 424",
            "time_event": "19:00",
            "description": "description",
            "first_storage_file": "1598551003.jpg",
            "longitude": "124124",
            "latitude": "12312.123123",
            "storage_file": 0,
            "storage": []
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to receive all the events , where In events will be all users Who belongs to events ,
and Data of the user who created event. For example :

```
{
    "success": true,
    "event": [
        {
            "id_event": 1,
            "id_user": 1,
            "name_event": "new event",
            "place_event": "Chocen, wladyslawa lokietka 424",
            "time_event": "19:00",
            "description": "description",
            "first_storage_file": "1598548420.jpg",
            "longitude": "124124",
            "latitude": "12312.123123",
            "storage_file": 1,
            "storage": [
                {
                    "id_storage": 1,
                    "id_event": 1,
                    "storage_file_title": "profile.jpg",
                    "created_at": null,
                    "updated_at": null
                }
            ]
        "users_member": [
                {
                    "id_user": 1,
                    "email": 1,
                    "profile_image": "profile.jpg",
                    "fullname": null,
                    "age": null
            "gender": null
                }
        {
                    "id_user": 1,
                    "email": 1,
                    "profile_image": "profile.jpg",
                    "fullname": null,
                    "age": null
            "gender": null
                }
        {
                    "id_user": 1,
                    "email": 1,
                    "profile_image": "profile.jpg",
                    "fullname": null,
                    "age": null
            "gender": null
                }
            ]
        "user_created_event": [
                {
                    "id_user": 1,
                    "email": 1,
                    "profile_image": "profile.jpg",
                    "fullname": null,
                    "age": null
            "gender": null
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id_event": 2,
            "id_user": 1,
            "name_event": "new event",
            "place_event": "Chocen, wladyslawa lokietka 424",
            "time_event": "19:00",
            "description": "description",
            "first_storage_file": "1598551003.jpg",
            "longitude": "124124",
            "latitude": "12312.123123",
            "storage_file": 0,
            "storage": []
        }
    ]
}
```

I created relationship in laravel.

USER Model :

```
public function event(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Event::class,'member_events', 'id_user', 'id_event');
        //return $this->belongsToMany(Event::class,'member_events', 'id_event', 'id_event', 'id_event')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

EVENT MODEL

```
public function storage(){
        return $this->hasMany(StorageEvent::class, 'id_event');
    }
    
    public function user(){
        //return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,member_events, 'id_user', 'id_user')->withTimestamps();
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'member_events', 'id_event', 'id_user');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your relationships are not correct.

Event should have a method

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class);
}
```

In User

```
public function event()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Event:class);
}
```

see https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: I created relationship more to more between table user and event . I have a connecting table member_events , Becausei create belongsToMany method.

Answer (score 0):

To have all of them on the response there is 2 ways :

1. (Pro level)you append them to your response for a defined endpoint. this is the efficient way because you will have them only for the endpoints that you defined.
   To do it you use the property $appends in your model, and declare getUsersAttribute and getEventAttribute that return each the eloquent relation with a get() to have objects collection and not the builder.
2. (Normal level)you can use the $with property, then they will be returned with your requested model

   protected $with = ['event','users'];

Check the Laravel documentation with your appropriate laravel version to see how to use the concepts that i mentioned.